# How to convert ReSharper's DotSettings file into human readable file?

Tags: resharper

Is there a tool/plugin that can read ReSharper's DotSettings file and create a html/doc/pdf etc with all the rules etc embedded in DotSettings file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It's not really intended to be a document in that manner - the settings aren't always self-documenting, so converting into a different file format won't necessarily help.

However, despite appearances, it is actually a pretty simple file format - it's an XML file of name/value pairs. So could be processed with a tool or plugin.

**OBLIGATORY NOTE**: There is no need to know this in order to use, consume or share settings. This is all implementation details...

The file is actually a XAML file, serialised as a WPF `ResourceDictionary` (although it's treated as plain XML internally). Each entry is a string, or boolean or whatever. The `x:Key` attribute provides a hierarchical key, with names in the hierarchy separated by the `/` character. E.g.:

```xml
<s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0F88A1C6C451B448B99CFE316153B889/Description/@EntryValue">Description of a live template</s:String>
```

This is an entry in the following hierarchy:

```
/
--Default
  --PatternsAndTemplates
    --LiveTemplates
      --Template
        --=0F88A1C6C451B448B99CFE316153B889
          --Description
```

This is the hierarchy you see when you select to export data from the "Manage Options" dialog. Each entry comes from a settings class defined in ReSharper, apart from the entry beginning with an equals sign `=`. This symbol denotes that this entry is from an "indexed value", meaning the `Template` segment is actually a list of items, each of which is keyed with a value, in this case, a guid, but could equally be a plain string name.

So, the `Template` segment could contain a number of these guid entries, one for each live template defined in the settings file. And this guid is still just another path in the hierarchy - each template guid can have entries underneath it, like the `Description` segment here.

Entries beginning with the at symbol `@` are metadata entries, e.g. `@EntryValue` means the value of the XML element is the value of the setting, so `Description/@EntryValue` is the value of the description. There are other metadata values, such as `@EntryIndexedValue` for simple indexed values, `@KeyIndexDefined` to show that an index exists or `@EntryIndexRemoved` to show that a value from another file (perhaps default settings, e.g. pre-defined live templates) has been deleted.

It is possible to get a small text description for each entry. The classes backing the settings entries inside ReSharper are decorated with attributes that provide a short description of the key, and the values. You can look for classes decorated with `SettingsKeyAttribute`. E.g.:

```C#
[SettingsKey(typeof(Missing), "Libraries of templates and patterns")]
public class PatternsAndTemplatesSettingsKey
{
}
```

This defines the `PatternsAndTemplates` part of the above path (the name is derived by convention, dropping any `Settings` or `SettingsKey` suffix).

The `typeof(Missing)` defines the parent settings key in the hierarchy. Here it's just using `System.Reflection.Missing` to indicate that there is no parent (the `/Default` in the path is a "mount point" for the data, allowing parallel hierarchies in the settings system).

Child segments in the path are also declared as classes marked with `SettingsKeyAttribute`, and values are public fields, marked with `SettingsEntryAttribute` or `SettingsIndexedEntryAttribute`.

```C#
[SettingsIndexedKey(typeof(LiveTemplatesSettings), "Single template", typeof(GuidIndex))]
public class TemplateSettings
{
  [SettingsEntry(null, "Template shortcut")] public string Shortcut;
  [SettingsEntry(null, "Template description")] public string Description;
  [SettingsEntry(null, "Template text")] public string Text;
  [SettingsEntry(false, "Template is disabled")] public bool IsDisabled;
  [SettingsEntry(false, "Reformat after expansion")] public bool Reformat;
  [SettingsEntry(false, "Shorten qualified references")] public bool ShortenQualifiedReferences;
  [SettingsEntry(false, "Is invisible")] public bool IsInvisible;
  [SettingsIndexedEntry("Categories")] public IIndexedEntry<string, string> Categories;
  [SettingsIndexedEntry("Custom properties")] public IIndexedEntry<string, string> CustomProperties;
  [SettingsIndexedEntry("Template applicability")] public IIndexedEntry<TemplateApplicability, bool> Applicability;    
}
```

And each attribute includes a short description of the field itself. (The initial value in the `SettingsEntryAttribute` constructor is a "default value", but it's not used like that. It's actually a value to be used if the settings system isn't yet initialised. It's used in perhaps 2 places in the ReSharper codebase, and so shouldn't be relied upon to be correct).

Also, there's an internal tool built into ReSharper that allows you to navigate and investigate the settings system. Run `devenv.exe /ReSharper.Internal` and navigate to ReSharper -> Internal -> Windows -> SettingsStoreView. It's internal, so don't expect polish and be warned that there are bugs...